# Jquery Template and Jquery 1.8 conflict

Tags: jquery

While using Jquery Template with latest Jquery version like 1.8, jquery template breaks if we have special charaters in ID, please refer the below link.

http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/03/find-jquery-bug-8-suspicious-selectors.html

Consider a scenario of ${OrderID} - used for div element id

```
<div id="Check${OrderID}">
</div>
```

Then while templating we have problems since id shouldn't contain special charaters in latest jquery version.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. what is your question?

Comment: I need dynamic divs and ${OrderID} will be updated dynamically with value , if the value was not updated intially jquery find using id selector will throw exception and i can't change the id since jquery template supports only ${   } to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var id = encodeURIComponent(id);
$('#' + id);
```

Comment: If i encode the id then the jquery templating i.e ${OrderID}  wont get the data dynamically